# when parameter is blank show value instead crystal report xi

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I have a report where I have an optional string parameter. This is Crystal Reports XI (11.0.0).  In the report, I would like to display 'All' when the report is run with the parameter left blank. I have tried the following:
I right click on the field -> Format Field -> Common -> Display String
    `if {?Location} = '' then 'all'`
    `if IsNull({?Location}) then
'All'`
    `if Length({?Location})< 1 then
'All'`
    `if Length(Trim({?Location}))< 1 then
'All'`

There is also nothing printed when I put 
`ToText(Length({?Location}))`
or 
    `ToText(IsNull({?Location}))`

Also related to this question is 
[How do I handle empty number fields/variables in Crystal Reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405759/how-do-i-handle-empty-number-fields-variables-in-crystal-reports) 
for which there was no accepted answer at the time of this submission. My googleing didn't turn up anything of worth.

Comment: It doesn't recognize HasValue as a function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the Display String property, make a formula instead:

```
If IsNull({?Location}) Or Trim({?Location}) = "" Then
    "All"
Else
    {?Location}
```

Now drop your @Formula into the report.